# Running unsigned javaws code

Tags: security, java

For a KVM remote console I need to be able to run a `jnlp` file. When I run it I get:

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. 
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:797)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:555)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:908)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:319)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:239)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:381)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:337)
at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:789)
... 2 more
```

I understand why you do not want your browser to run arbitrary unsigned code.

But in this situation I do not have a chance to neither change nor sign the code, as it comes from the KVM device.

- Can I tell Java that this one applet is OK to run unsigned?

  - If not: Can I tell Java running all applets from that domain are OK to run unsigned?

    - If not: Can I tell Java running all applets are OK to run unsigned?
- Are there better options, given that I cannot change the code?

I am currently using Linux Mint and Chrome.

Answer (score 20):

**Allow unsigned JARS**

**TO:**

> .java/deployment/deployment.properties

**ADD:**

```
deployment.security.level=ALLOW_UNSIGNED
```

**NOTE:**

> .java/deployment

is an alias to

> .config/icedtea-web

---

**Allow weakly signed JARS:**

If above doesn't work, try commenting out lines including:

> disabledAlgorithms

example

```
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024
```

from *java.security*

> /etc/java-*-openjdk/security/java.security

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. Seems like the original error message can mean many different things.

Comment: For Dell Poweredge M1000e removing `MD5` from `jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms` fixes the `java` remote console to it's blade servers

Comment: Did not works for me. Do I need to restart system (or display manager)?

Comment: Disabling `jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms` helped me.

Answer (score 7):

The versions of icedTea included in Ubuntu 14.04 have a new control panel that includes the possibility to configure policies that really work.

[image: The Control Panel now allows to modify the Policy File]

Now you can allow the execution of *unowned code*. If you are concerned about security, allow that permissions only from the particular CodeBase of you application

[image: Allow the execution of unowned code]

I have tried doing the same in Ubuntu 12.04.x with no success at all. In previous Ubuntu versions, java.policy files seem to be ignored.

Comment: I'd point out that you launch the configuration with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/itweb-settings` if there is not an easy GUI way to do it.

Comment: What command can I use to launch this configuration window? I'm using icedtea.

Comment: `/usr/bin/itweb-settings` launches the IcedTea Web Control Panel.

Comment: I performed this action, but still get the error =(

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, I was able to achieve this by commenting the SHA1 `denyafter`:

```
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, \
      DSA keySize < 1024, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
#, SHA1 denyAfter 2019-01-01
```

Comment: What file did you make that change in?